# why does integer input give error invalid literal for int()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am keep getting an error if I put in something other than an integer. I want the loop to reiterate if say enter is pushed or if a letter is input. I want to give the user the error message I put in the else statement and return back to asking for the input again. Thank you.

```
pizza_high = 0

  while not repeat:
    pizza_high = int(input('How many pizzas would you like to order:'))
    if pizza_high != int:
      repeat = True
    else:
      print('**ERROR** Please use whole numbers only!!')
      pizza_high = 0
  for x in range(0, pizza_high): 
    print('pizzas')
```

This is the input if "5" was selected, it works properly.

```
How many pizzas would you like to order: 5
pizzas
pizzas
pizzas
pizzas
pizzas
```

However if I hit enter or put in a letter it gives this error

```
How many pizzas would you like to order: t
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ';'
```

Comment: Your code can't even work, since `pizza_high` is set to a str on the `pizza_high = input(...)`, causing an error in the `range` statement. `input` doesn't magically transform its result into an integer or other types.

Comment: And yes, of course you get a (Value)error if you try to convert a string that is not a number to a number. try-except can help there.

Comment: yes, I didnt get it copied over properly. The output with 5 works when int(input) is used but still gives error with int(input) if say a letter is selected. I want it to print my error message and loop not ValueError out

Comment: @MatthewPhaneuf you simply catch the `ValueError`, print the message and allow the loop to iterate again. If it gets past the `input` line you can set your condition to end the loop. `if pizza_high != int:` is not a valid way of checking if a value is of type int and even if it was it wouldnt be reached as the uncaught exception already caused your program to exit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic strategies. You can check whether a cast to integer will work or just try it and catch the error. Here are examples of both, with other cleanup added. For instance, its more straight forward to break out of the while than have an extra variable. And mind your 4 spaces for indents.

```
while True:
    pizza_high = input('How many pizzas would you like to order:')
    if pizza_high.isdigit():
        pizza_high = int(pizza_high)
        break
    else:
        print('**ERROR** Please use whole numbers only!!')

for x in range(0, pizza_high): 
    print('pizzas')


while True:
    try:
        pizza_high = int(input('How many pizzas would you like to order:'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('**ERROR** Please use whole numbers only!!')

for x in range(0, pizza_high): 
    print('pizzas')
```